# Detect Fling distance android

Tags: android

I am working on an application which requires me to manually handle the fling process rather than giving it to the framework. What I want to achieve is basically calculate the amount of pixels a listview moves when it receives a fling action. As the scroll method already provides distance in form of delta, I have handled it easily. But is there a way to get fling distance as only velocity parameter is being passed in the super method.

Note- I have to move another view in accordance with the fling distance, so I need to get it simultaneously just like onScroll provides it.
Thanks.

Comment: just override onScroll end onFling methods of your OnGestureListener

Comment: That is ok, I overrided those functions. But the onFling method: `public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
    float velocityY) ` , doesn't provide distance, just provides fling velocity. What I want is the fling distance.

Comment: As per the docs, e1 is the first ACTION_DOWN event which triggered the scroll. And e2 is the ACTION_UP event after which fling occurs. My requirement is to get the distance after ACTION_UP event, whereas e2-e1 would provide the scroll distance, correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: "to get the distance after ACTION_UP event"? how can you imagine that? your finger doesn't touch the screen after action up so what events can you get?

Comment: I know that is why I posted this here. Forget the distance, what I am required to do is move a custom view in accordance with the amount of scrolling my list does. For scrolling events, I get the distance and I move the view accordingly, but how can I move in accordance with the pixels the list moves when I provide fling movement. That is another form of my question.

Comment: Hi pskink, Can I use this scroller class for getting the amount of pixels my listview scrolls upward. Though I know there are other methods too for getting the top position of a scrollable view, but as I don't have the instance of listview available in other file, I can't use those methods. Regarding scroller, I googled and found some examples, but I am not sure whether this can be used to detect the number of pixels the list actually scrolls upwards or downwards. Thanks.

Comment: or you can use OnScrollListener

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is passed 3 years but no answer yet. I found some workaround to achieve it.

Actually it is kind of advanced topic as there are a lot of nuances but basically you can refer to Android source code(OverScroller class in particular) and use this method. You will need to copy it into your class and use it.

```
 private double getSplineFlingDistance(int velocity) {
     final double l = getSplineDeceleration(velocity);
     final double decelMinusOne = DECELERATION_RATE - 1.0;
     return mFlingFriction * PHYSICAL_COEF * Math.exp(DECELERATION_RATE / decelMinusOne * l);
 }
```

Other methods and values can be obtained from the same class.
The link to the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/OverScroller.java

Keep in mind that in some devices the value can be different (not too much). Some vendors change the formula depending on their requirements and hardware to make it more smooth.

Comment: I can't understand why this answer is accepted. How do I get value mFlingFriction?

Comment: @XueQing, thank you for pointing it out. Please check associated source code from the Android Framework. The link is provided in the answer. You can see more details about the logic there.

Comment: float mFlingFriction = ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction();   I can get that value, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the original question ended up with nothing, but it was formulated pretty good, so I landed here and started my research. Here are my results.

My question was: What is the final `value` at the end of Android standard [`FlingAnimation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/dynamicanimation/animation/FlingAnimation)?

```java
    new FlingAnimation(new FloatValueHolder(0f))
        .addEndListener((animation, canceled, value, velocity) -> {
            ? value
```

I needed that value before animation start based on the start velocity to make some preparations at the destination point of the `FlingAnimation`.

Actually I started with [`Overscroller.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/OverScroller.java) mentioned by @Adil Aliyev. I collected all the portions of code, but the result was way less, that came from the animation.

Then I took a look into [`FlingAnimation.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/oreo-dev/dynamic-animation/src/android/support/animation/FlingAnimation.java) in pair with [`DynamicAnimation.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/oreo-dev/dynamic-animation/src/android/support/animation/DynamicAnimation.java).

The key function in [`FlingAnimation.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/oreo-dev/dynamic-animation/src/android/support/animation/FlingAnimation.java) to start the research was:

```java
    MassState updateValueAndVelocity(float value, float velocity, long deltaT) {
```

After playing with some equations I composed this final code. It gives not totally exact estimation to the last digit, but very close. I will use it for my needs. You are welcome too:

```java
    final float DEFAULT_FRICTION = -4.2f;
    final float VELOCITY_THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER = 1000f / 16f;
    float mFriction = 1.1f * DEFAULT_FRICTION; // set here friction that you set in .setFriction(1.1f) or 1 by default
    final float THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER = 0.75f;
    float mVelocityThreshold = THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER * VELOCITY_THRESHOLD_MULTIPLIER;
    
    double time = Math.log(mVelocityThreshold / startVelocity) * 1000d / mFriction;
    double flingDistance = startVelocity / mFriction * (Math.exp(mFriction * time / 1000d) - 1);
```